# How to separate touching outlines of areas inside a polygonmesh?

Tags: c++, algorithm, mesh

I have a 3D polygonmesh, which has some holes in it's surface. I calculated the mean curvature for each node to find the holes and marked the nodes of a hole with a flag. In a second step I looked at the nodes of the holes and collected those, which have neighbours which aren't part of any hole area. That are my outlines.

Now I see that their are some sort of islands inside a hole. Because of that I've got inner outlines, which sometimes touch each other. (blue lines inside the picture)

[image: Surface holes with borders]

I want to find out which is the outermost border of them. But I don't find a clue how to say for sure at a fork of the border, if I'm going on on the outer line or if I'm entering an inner outline.

I thought about finding the shortest way between fork nodes. But it is possible that their are some huge convexities on my outer border. So this doesn't work.

My second idea was to determine which direction I'm walking, while going from node to node. But I can't get a fixed node in the centre of one hole to compare distances.

Here is some common data about an outline:

- one outline can touch multiple other outlines
- another outline can be touched multiple times by the same outline
- an outline is a continuous line
- it must not be circle like shaped

I'm thankful for every hint how too clearly separate the outer line.

Comment: You could try to fill all the outlined shapes with a non-zero winding mode. If you then take the borders of the filled shapes, those would correspond to the outer lines. This assumes that you have at least one point that you know lies outside of the outer line.

Comment: Is there any planar projection of your mesh, which allows to analyse it in two dimensions? If so, use the standard 'point in the polygon' algorithm: if an A outline's vertex AV lays inside the B outline, then B is outer outline. If there's no C outline outer to B, then B is outermost outline of its group.

Comment: You don't tell us how you have found the holes in your mesh. I think finding the outline of these and the outline of the islands is basically the same: Find all edges that are connected to only one polygon. And you can classify your polygons into surfaces with a flood-fill style algorithm that walks along the edges. Both algorithms will require a map of edges to adjacent polygons and will work on polygon connectivity only.

Comment: @CiaPan Unfortunately, there is no reliable way to get a planar projection of each hole.

Comment: @M Oehm I added information about how I got the holes and the outlines to my question. The above answers also brought me to realize, that it might be the simplest way to take a node outside one hole and walk over neighbour nodes until I hit border nodes. So I know for sure, which nodes build the outermost line.

Comment: So the "islands" are there by error and you only want the outer outlines of the holes? Or, rather, you want the islands to be part of the hole?

Comment: @M Oehm Correct, I want only the outer outline for each hole and the nodes inside an "island" should be marked with the same flag as the surrounding hole.

Comment: I hoped their might be a way to accomplish this only with the information about one hole (nodes of the hole, outline nodes). So I wanted to look at all nodes inside such a inner outline and mark them. But when a inner outline touches the outermost, I can't decide if my none-hole-node is part of an island or of the area outside the hole.